# Как установить java EE

Tags: java

Решил изучать java и начал, естественно, с установки jdk. Загуглил "jdk" прошел по ссылке, выбрал java ee, перешел во вкладку downloads, тыкнул download java ee 7 sdk update 2 и проблема в том, что он мне предлагает скачать только какой то непонятный архив, а судя по видео урокам (они 2013 года) он должен был мне предложить менюшку, где нужно выбрать конкретный установщик под свою систему. Дак где и как сказать java ee? Или сначала нужно скачать java se, а потом установить java ee? Или как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот ссылка](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

Последняя версия JDK

Comment: Ну это же SE. Сначала ее установить? А как потом по верх нее прикрутить EE?

Comment: Если нужна другая версия нужно искать в архивах Oracle.

Comment: @user226620 сначала уточните что именно вам нужно.

Comment: @user226620 если что то качайте архив старых версий JDK и ищите там необходимую вам версию.

Comment: Мне нужна java EE. Но, как я сейчас понял, он без jdk и вопрос в том, как мне установить java EE? Как я понял, нужно сначала установить jdk, которая идет вместе с java SE, но тогда вопрос, как установить потом поверх SE EE.

Comment: @user226620 для начала изучения Java я бы посоветовал сначала использовать SE. Java EE подходит для средних и крупных предприятий

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, я понял.

Answer (score 3):

Если быть точным, то установить Java EE невозможно, так как это набор стандартов, а не конкретное ПО. То, что вы скачиваете - это сервер приложений Glassfish 4, включающий в себя набор библиотек, реализующих стандарт Java EE. Распакуйте архив куда-нибудь, запустите сервер в соответствии с прилагающейся к нему инструкцией и эксперементируйте.

И лучше не пользуйтесь устаревшими видеоуроками, иначе будете постоянно попадать в непонятные ситуации.